# How to display current date and time on Wpf statusbar

Tags: c#, wpf, date, statusbar

I want to know how to display current date and time on a WPF statusbar.

I know this is too basic a question, but I am new to .net WPF,
and I know this can be done in a Form application easily.

Thanks in advance.

Ting

Comment: Please, show us what you've tried already

Comment: instead of trying anything, i have been looking for some similar control available in Form application's toolbox. I am sure I can manage to display the date and time anyway, but am afraid that will not be the common practice, due to lack of knowledge of WPF. I had thought, a ready-to-use control will be there to be used, instead of making it by myself. So the question is really is not how to display a time or date, but in what way. And should I give up my Form application's thinking and just do this kind of work by myself code?

Answer (score 2):

Create a wpf project. In your `MainWindow.xaml` add the `StatusBar` and handle `Loaded` event of window.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="private" x:Name="myDateTime"/>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` add the following namespaces (if they are not exist):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

And in the `Loaded` enevt handler you can use [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netcore-3.1) for update textblock text property every second:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, (object s, EventArgs ev) =>
   {
      this.myDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
   }, this.Dispatcher);
   timer.Start();
}
```

Also there are a lot of examples for customize wpf controls using `Template` and `Style` properties. just search for it.

- [Styles and templates in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview)
- [The WPF StatusBar control](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/statusbar-control/)

and many more.

Also you can implement your custom `WPFTimer`. This simple implementation get you an idea for do this.

```
public class WPFTimer : TextBlock
{
   #region static

   public static readonly DependencyProperty IntervalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Interval", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(WPFTimer), new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), IntervalChangedCallback));
   public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRunningProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsRunning", typeof(bool), typeof(WPFTimer), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsRunningChangedCallback));

   private static void IntervalChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      WPFTimer wpfTimer = (WPFTimer)d;
      wpfTimer.timer.Interval = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
   }

   private static void IsRunningChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      WPFTimer wpfTimer = (WPFTimer)d;
      wpfTimer.timer.IsEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
   }

   #endregion

   private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;

   [Category("Common")]
   public TimeSpan Interval
   {
      get
      {
         return (TimeSpan)this.GetValue(IntervalProperty);
      }
      set
      {
         this.SetValue(IntervalProperty, value);
      }
   }

   [Category("Common")]
   public bool IsRunning
   {
      get
      {
         return (bool)this.GetValue(IsRunningProperty);
      }
      set
      {
         this.SetValue(IsRunningProperty, value);
      }
   }

   public WPFTimer()
   {
      this.timer = new DispatcherTimer(this.Interval, DispatcherPriority.Normal,this.Timer_Tick ,this.Dispatcher);
      this.timer.IsEnabled = false;
   }

   private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.SetValue(TextProperty, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"));
   }
}
```

And now you have a control that can use it in the designer.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
            <local:WPFTimer IsRunning="True"/>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: many thanks! I ever thought of trying this way, but imagined there would a way like what I did in a Form application: just put a control (item) on it. For WPF, really, I have to do such kind of work to display a time? why dont display it automatically for me, I thought that is the purpose of using a control.

Comment: @Chengting Your welcome. But this is not a hard work. wpf has a rich designer that do more of this works visually. But if you mean a control like windows forms timer? [in wpf usual time is the `DispatcherTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410783/5758877).

Comment: @Chengting Also you can implement your custom `WPFTimer`. see my edit.

Comment: yes,the WPFTimer is what I expected. I took it for granted that there is such a control ready to use there in toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way, using wpf animation and binding, and no background code :)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--Set x: share to get the latest every time-->
            <system:DateTime x:Key="DateTime"
                                x:Shared="False" />
            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
                <!--Use keyframe animation to update datetime -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext"
                                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                AutoReverse="False">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="50%"
                                            Value="{StaticResource DateTime}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--Get datetime from DataContext-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=DataContext.Now}"
                    DataContext="{StaticResource DateTime}">
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

or like this,a real clock

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="time" Tag="{x:Static system:DateTime.Now}" />

        <TransformGroup x:Key="transformHour">
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Source={StaticResource time},Path=Tag.Hour}"
                                Y="{Binding Source={StaticResource time},Path=Tag.Minute}" />
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="30 0 0.5 0 0 0" />
        </TransformGroup>

        <TransformGroup x:Key="transformMinute">
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Source={StaticResource time},Path=Tag.Minute}"
                                Y="{Binding Source={StaticResource time},Path=Tag.Second}" />
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="6 0 0.1 0 0 0" />
        </TransformGroup>

        <TransformGroup x:Key="transformSecond">
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Source={StaticResource time},Path=Tag.Second}" />
            <MatrixTransform Matrix="6 0 0 0 0 0" />
        </TransformGroup>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeDashCap" Value="Triangle" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>

            <Path Data="M 0 -90 A 90 90 0 1 1 -0.01 -90"
                StrokeDashArray="0 3.14157" />

            <Path Data="M 0 -90 A 90 90 0 1 1 -0.01 -90"
                StrokeDashArray="0 7.854"
                StrokeThickness="6" />

            <Border Background="LightBlue" Width="10" Height="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="bor_Second"
                                        Angle="{Binding Source={StaticResource transformSecond},Path=Value.OffsetX}" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>

            <Border Background="LightGreen" Width="10" Height="60" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="bor_Minute"
                                        Angle="{Binding Source={StaticResource transformMinute},Path=Value.OffsetX}" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>

            <Border Background="LightGray" Width="10" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="bor_Hour"
                                        Angle="{Binding Source={StaticResource transformHour},Path=Value.OffsetX}" />
                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>

        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bor_Hour"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                    IsAdditive="True"
                                    Duration="12:0:0"
                                    From="0" To="360"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bor_Minute"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                    IsAdditive="True"
                                    Duration="1:0:0"
                                    From="0" To="360"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bor_Second"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                    IsAdditive="True"
                                    Duration="0:1:0"
                                    From="0"
                                    To="360"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
</Window>
```

[Create a clock using only xaml code in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350358/create-a-digital-clock-using-only-xaml-code-in-wpf/61933419#61933419)